# How to generate javadoc in an Android project with JDK 11

Tags: java, android, gradle, javadoc, java-11

**My setup:**

- Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.1
- Gradle 6.2.1
- JDK 11

I have a working configuration for building Javadoc using JDK 8. It looks like this (based on https://www.stkent.com/2016/02/05/adventures-with-javadocs-part-2.html):

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    from javadoc.destinationDir
    archiveClassifier.set('javadoc')
}
```

As commented in the article there is a large number of warnings about classes, etc. When using JDK 11 these warnings are now errors. And even if ignoring the errors I can see that the javadoc is not generated properly. Previously it included HTML with all the packages/classes but with JDK 11 there is only a metadata folder with a MANIFEST.MF file (contains: "Manifest-Version: 1.0").

**What could be the cause for this changed behavior?**

**Update:**
Upon request in the comments I have added an example of the type of errors I get (as I mentioned, this type of errors is in the referenced article but in JDK8 they are just warnings):

```
 symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
/builds/myproject/src/main/java/com/mycompany/package/Bar.java:7: error: package com.mycompany.package does not exist
import com.mycompany.package.Foo;

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Software changes. Stuff gets deprecated. But it's hard to help you without knowing *what* errors you're getting.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca maybe try [pressing more buttons](https://xkcd.com/722/)

Comment: I have now added an example of the errors to the main ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved adding `--ignore-source-errors` option to the javadoc.

For that you should add inside your javadoc task the following line:

```
options.addBooleanOption('-ignore-source-errors', true)
```